Forgot the name of a group property
I forgot what is the notation, or definition or the name of the number of subgroups (or elements), product of which is a subgroup $G$ (or element), I don't remember it is denoted $cov(G)$ or $con(G)$ or something like that, it might be that this is defined for rings and not groups so I got that confused, I thought it meant the invariance of a group but couldn't find the definition online.
The definition I forgot the name of given formally is just $$cov(g)=|\{(a, b)\in G^2: a*b=g\}|$$ or $$cov(g)=|\{\{a, b\}\subseteq G: a*b=g\}$$ (when $G$ is abelian) and is equipped with group operation $*$
For example the finite group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{×}$ (integers Modulo 5 coprime) given by the map $(a, b)\mapsto ab\pmod{5}$ has $cov(1)=cov(4)=3$ and $cov(2)=cov(3)=2$   since each of those numbers in $G$ can be written as 3 products and 2 products of different 2 numbers respectively (i.e $3\equiv1\cdot3\equiv2\cdot4\pmod{5}$)

"Each element has $3$ products of distinct elements" doesn't make any sense to me.

Unfortunately I don't understand the first sentence (or the example); can you clarify your intended meaning?

@AlexKruckman I didn't want to write it formally/rigorously to make it short.

Brevity is good, but not if it comes at the expense of clarity. In fact, even after you added more details, I still don't understand your example.

Doesn't every element in a group show once and only once in each row/column of group's Cayley table? But I might be misinterpreting anything.

Your post is still not clear. Since $ab=g\iff b=a^{-1}g$,$$|{(a, b)\in G^2: a*b=g}|=|G|.$$

@AnneBauval your first statement is obvious, but $cov(G)\neq |G|$, again as given in the example of the ring of integers modulo 5 that is also a group, you have $2=12=34$ hence $cov(2)=3$. Sorry I should've written that definition from the beginning

My first (obvious) statement proves the claim which follows it. The purpose of my comment was precisely to highlight the mistakes in your example, by elaborating Kan't's comment. The way you defined $cov$, for any group $G$ you have $$\forall g\in G\quad cov(g)=|G|.$$You  just wrote $cov(2)=3$. You probably meant $cov(2)=2$, but actually, $cov(2)=4$. You forgot half of the set:$${(a,b)\in(\Bbb Z_5)^2\mid ab=2}={(a,a^{-1}2)\mid a\in\Bbb Z_5}$$ $$={(1,1\cdot2),(2,3\cdot2),(3,2\cdot2),(4,4\cdot2)}$$  $$={(1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3)}.$$

If by "$cov(g)$", you meant $|{{a,b} \subseteq G : a * b = g}|$, then you would get $cov(1)=cov(4)=3$ and $cov(2)=cov(3)=2$, which is exactly what you have written. So, did you really mean $|{{a,b} \subseteq G : a * b = g}|$ instead of $|{(a, b) \in G^2 : a * b = g}|$? Note, however, that using ${a, b}$ instead of $(a, b)$ would only make sense if $G$ is an abelian group. It would not make sense if $a$ and $b$ do not necessarily commute in a nonabelian group.

@GeoffreyTrang,AnneBauval You are both right, I didn't notice that $G$ is abelian, I will clarify that in the post
